# Cannot resolve symbol. Unable to add location data to EXIF of an image.

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add google location data to the EXIF header of the images taken in my application. So far, I'm able to to get the location using [fused location provider](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) and toast it in the MainActivity. But when trying to write the location data to the EXIF Header of the images taken in a thread, I'm not able to get the Location object there. It is showing `'Cannot resolve symbol 'location'`. Any help is appreciated.

**MainActivity.java**

```
private TestThread myThread;
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        System.loadLibrary("NativeImageProcessor");

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                        if (location != null) {
                            // ...
                            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Latitude:" + latitude+", Longitude:"+longitude,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
               ...
               ...
            takePicture();
```

**TestThread.java**

```
   ....
    private void saveBitmap(String name, Bitmap bitmap, String timeStamp) {
    File photo = CommonUtil.getFileName(timeStamp, name);
    if (photo.exists()) photo.delete();
    try {
        Bitmap image = applyBrightnessContrast(bitmap);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(photo.getPath());
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
        CommonUtil.showProgressDialog(mContext, null, false);
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        CommonUtil.showProgressDialog(mContext, null, false);
        Log.e("PictureDemo", "Exception in photoCallback", e);
    }
    markGeoTagImage(photo.getPath(),location);// Here is the Error. 
 }

public static void markGeoTagImage(String imagePath,Location location)
{
    try {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, GPS.convert(location.getLatitude()));
        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF, GPS.latitudeRef(location.getLatitude()));
        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, GPS.convert(location.getLongitude()));
        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF, GPS.longitudeRef(location.getLongitude()));
        SimpleDateFormat fmt_Exif = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss");
        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME,fmt_Exif.format(new Date(location.getTime())));
        exif.saveAttributes();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: try to pass your received location in onSuccess to a global attribute and use your global attribute in markGeoTagImage

Comment: As 'public static string= null;' in the Activity?? It would be great if you explain it in the code.

Comment: I post answer for you , you should define Object from type Location and initialize it in onSuccess when location receive

Comment: @MHP Can you please have a look at this question of mine? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46261285/how-to-get-integer-value-of-a-seekbardialoguepreference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define new global attribute for example `mLocation` and pass received `location` to it and use it like this:

```
public static Location mLocation; // this is your location

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
try {
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

  getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    System.loadLibrary("NativeImageProcessor");

    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                    if (location != null) {
                        mLocation = location; // we pass received location to our global location object
                        // ...
                        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Latitude:" + latitude+", Longitude:"+longitude,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
           ...
           ...
        takePicture();
```

and then use `mLocation` in your EXIF , like this:

```
private void saveBitmap(String name, Bitmap bitmap, String timeStamp) {
  File photo = CommonUtil.getFileName(timeStamp, name);
  if (photo.exists()) photo.delete();
  try {
         Bitmap image = applyBrightnessContrast(bitmap);
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(photo.getPath());
         image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
         fos.close();
         CommonUtil.showProgressDialog(mContext, null, false);
      } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
         CommonUtil.showProgressDialog(mContext, null, false);
         Log.e("PictureDemo", "Exception in photoCallback", e);
      }
  if(mLocation != null)// check we have location or not
     markGeoTagImage(photo.getPath(),mLocation);
}
```

Comment: It is still showing not resolving. My thread is in a different class.

Comment: so pass mLocation to saveBitmap in a way

Comment: Issue solved. I just made it ` public static Location mLocation `. Then It came there in the thread. Please update the answer. I'll up vote it. Thanks a lot .

Comment: @NewCoder great!